# Add "Sale" or "Discount" text to a product display using drupal commerce?

Tags: 7, commerce

I have been searching for an answer a long time with no success at all.

I am buildind a drupal commerce website and i would like to show on a specific products the word "Sale" or "Discount" as showing in the picture below (like the green Sale Tag).

[image: Notice the "Sale!" Green Tag]

I can do it using photoshop but is really a pain to go over hundred of product just to photoshop a "Sale" text on every product picture in question.

Can someone point me to a specific module that can do such job ?!
Note that i know basic CSS so if this could be done using some CSS code, a starting push from any body will be appreciated !

Thank you,

Comment: you can simply assign a "class" to particular products and css will handle the rest.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally resolved...

For the sake of anyone having the same question, the trick is to add a "CSS Class" to the field in question and use some CSS codes to achieve whatever the design you like.

1) Create the **field in question** in the correspondant content type.

2) Goto manage display of that content type, select what "view" you want to use between the available views on the "manage display" page and then make the **field in question** visible and choose the format to be: **Linked and Wrapped** and then click on field settings where you should:

_ Wrap the title in tag: **DIV**

_ Link title to: **Nothing**

_ Add your class: **yourclass**

3) Use **yourclass** and add some CSS Code to design the content of the **field in question**.

NOTE: The good thing is that when the **field in question** is **empty** all the design just disappear and you will see nothing on your product which is awesome.

Answer (score 3):

With [Views Conditional](https://www.drupal.org/project/views_conditional) you can make it that if `Label Discount Name` is equal to `Sale` then `<div class="sale"><img src="...."></div>` Otherwise output nothing.

Then do the same for Discount.

> Views Conditional is a simple module that allows you to define
>   conditionals (if xxx then yyy) with fields in views. Conditions
>   include:
>
> ```
> Equal To
> Not Equal To
> Greater Than
> Less Than
> Empty
> Not Empty
> ```
>
> Views conditional allows you to output text based on the result of the
>   condition.

Comment: in your answer you mentioned the img src but i am trying to add a "sale" text to the content type so whatever the product or image will be, once the "sale" text exist the design will take effect and once the "sale" text is removed the design just disappear ! Is that possible to be done using your answer above ? Thank you for your help!

Comment: `i am trying to add a "sale" text to the content type so whatever the product or image will be, once the "sale" text exist the design will take effect` yes, my answer already takes that into account. As the views conditional checks if the text of `Label Discount Name` is equal to sale. I read your "answer" so I already knew you already created a field (Label Discount Name) in your content type which will have the sale/clearance text.

Comment: Alright, thank you so much i will go more in deep using the views conditional and revert back here with any issue i face, if any.